# ASP.NET MVC: Handling User Session Timeout and Redirecting to Login Page Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm facing an issue with session timeout in my application. Despite setting the timeout in the web.config, the application doesn't redirect the user to the login page after the session has expired.

Here's my `web.config` authentication configuration:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" 
           cookieless="UseCookies" name=".ASPXAUTHDEALERMODULE" />
</authentication>
```

I've tried implementing various solutions, including filters and events like `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_PostAcquireRequestState`, but the redirect doesn't seem to work as expected.

The issue appears to be related to the redirection process. Interestingly, I have an identical `web.config` in another application where it functions as intended, redirecting users after the timeout period.

Could someone provide guidance on how to properly handle session timeout and ensure that users are redirected to the login page upon expiration? Is there a recommended approach or best practice for achieving this in ASP.NET?

Comment: App will use cookie until cookie is deleted or cookie expires.  Each retry is a new Request.  There is no "Redirect".  You make a Request and get back a Response when using HTTP Client and then connection closes.  Is working code HTTP Client or HTTP Socket?

Comment: `Application_PostAcquireRequestState` not working?  Or you want to implement an automatic landing page after expiration?

Comment: @JasonPan I need to implement someway to show to users that the session is expired, the planned scenario is redirecting the page do login screen, but all ways I try to achieve this, the application stucks on the last page or show an error about the expiration and I need to go to login manually

Comment: @jdweng I'm using HTTP Client

Comment: You need to delete the cookie https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178195(v=vs.100)

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to add a timer to JavaScript that will immediately use windows.location to redirect after monitoring that the current page has no action and starting a countdown of 20 minutes without responding.

Comment: @JasonPan, thanks for your help, I did this and it was the only way that worked, but I needed to keep the timeout in the web.config, so the final solution was:

- Configure the 20 minute timeout in web.config and JS as well;
- Monitor user clicks to trigger the JS timeout and redirect the page;
- Create an empty request and apply it to each user click to synchronize the user click with the web.config timeout, considering this timeout is renewed with each new request;

The solution is now in Code Review, but I'm waiting to hear what they tell me about these empty requests